# Handling hiss at 192K

Tags: 192k, hiss

I like capturing low level sounds at 192K and making them larger than life by down-pitching them via sample rate.

One problem I sometimes run into is that the hiss of my preamp is a bit too much because I have it boosted so high, and when it gets down-pitched two octaves, that hiss that was previously around 10K and above is somewhere around 4K and it is very apparent.

Do any of you have a similar phenomenon when you record and down-pitch sounds from 192K, and what sequence do you noise reduce it? Most of my noise reduction plug-ins don't work at 192K anyway, so do you drop it to 96K and reduce it there, and then drop it to 48K?

I'm curious if anyone has run into this before and what you do to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use noise reduction you will always introduce some measure of digital artifacts. And you should be especially wary at the higher sample rates, because once you drop your sounds down a few octaves you will likely notice it more.

I think your best approach is to stave off the problem at its root, which is the preamp. Try positioning your mic closer to the sound source, or try a different (and hopefully quieter) preamp. Also, don't forget about the rest of your signal chain; the hiss could be coming from your microphone, the cable, or the console.

Comment: Thanks Jay, always good answers. Mind if I ask what you think is the best quality+quiet preamp available out there?

Comment: No advice re. preamps since what I use is mostly for field recording rather than studio use. But re. microphones I highly recommend the MKH-800. Very sensitive and insanely quiet.

Answer (score 1):

Izotope RX does work at native sample rates.  I've been known to address some obv problems that are outside my hearing range just by visually identifing them.

alternatively just wait until you hear a sound in a downpitched context before de-noising it.

Comment: There's the 15th reason I've been given on this site to get Izotope RX - I guess it's time to actually get it now, eh? Thanks for the answer.